# spark sql 1.x. NotImplementedError: no parse rules

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

when I run some query by spark sql(hivecontext) it complains like below.

which syntax will cause this?
I am using spark 1.6 and hive 1.2

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Unsupported language features in query: SELECT i.*, 
            from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20170221','yyyyMMdd'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") bounce_date
            FROM 
              (SELECT country,
                     device_id,
                     os_name,
                     app_ver
              FROM jpl_band_orc
              WHERE yyyymmdd='20170221'
                      AND scene_id='app_intro'
                      AND action_id='scene_enter'
                      AND classifier='app_intro'
              GROUP BY  country, device_id, os_name, app_ver ) i
            LEFT JOIN 
              (SELECT device_id
              FROM jpl_band_orc
              WHERE yyyymmdd='20170221'
                      AND scene_id='band_list'
                      AND action_id='scene_enter'
                      AND device_id IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCT device_id
                FROM jpl_band_orc x
                WHERE yyyymmdd='20170221'
                        AND scene_id='app_intro'
                        AND action_id='scene_enter'
                        AND classifier='app_intro' ) ) s
                  ON i.device_id = s.device_id
            WHERE s.device_id is null
TOK_QUERY 8, 0,425, 10
  TOK_FROM 8, 28,412, 10
    TOK_LEFTOUTERJOIN 8, 36,412, 10
      TOK_SUBQUERY 8, 36,186, 10
        TOK_QUERY 8, 37,182, 10
          TOK_FROM 8, 91,93, 10
            TOK_TABREF 8, 93,93, 10
              TOK_TABNAME 8, 93,93, 10
                jpl_band_orc 8, 93,93, 10
          TOK_INSERT 0, -1,182, 0
            TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
              TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
                TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
            TOK_SELECT 4, 37,84, 13
              TOK_SELEXPR 4, 39,39, 13
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 4, 39,39, 13
                  country 4, 39,39, 13
              TOK_SELEXPR 5, 54,54, 12
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 5, 54,54, 12
                  device_id 5, 54,54, 12
              TOK_SELEXPR 6, 69,69, 12
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 6, 69,69, 12
                  os_name 6, 69,69, 12
              TOK_SELEXPR 7, 84,84, 12
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 7, 84,84, 12
                  app_ver 7, 84,84, 12
            TOK_WHERE 12, 100,161, 13
              AND 12, 102,161, 13
                AND 11, 138,138, 13
                  AND 10, 119,119, 13
                    = 9, 102,104, 19
                      TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 9, 102,102, 11
                        yyyymmdd 9, 102,102, 11
                      '20170221' 9, 104,104, 20
                    = 10, 121,123, 25
                      TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 10, 121,121, 17
                        scene_id 10, 121,121, 17
                      'app_intro' 10, 123,123, 26
                  = 11, 140,142, 26
                    TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 11, 140,140, 17
                      action_id 11, 140,140, 17
                    'scene_enter' 11, 142,142, 27
                = 12, 159,161, 27
                  TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 12, 159,159, 17
                    classifier 12, 159,159, 17
                  'app_intro' 12, 161,161, 28
            TOK_GROUPBY 13, 168,182, 15
              TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 13, 173,173, 15
                country 13, 173,173, 15
              TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 13, 176,176, 24
                device_id 13, 176,176, 24
              TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 13, 179,179, 35
                os_name 13, 179,179, 35
              TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 13, 182,182, 44
                app_ver 13, 182,182, 44
        i 13, 186,186, 54
      TOK_SUBQUERY 16, 201,391, 10
        TOK_QUERY 16, 202,387, 10
          TOK_FROM 16, 211,213, 10
            TOK_TABREF 16, 213,213, 10
              TOK_TABNAME 16, 213,213, 10
                jpl_band_orc 16, 213,213, 10
          TOK_INSERT 0, -1,387, 0
            TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
              TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
                TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
            TOK_SELECT 15, 202,204, 13
              TOK_SELEXPR 15, 204,204, 13
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 15, 204,204, 13
                  device_id 15, 204,204, 13
            TOK_WHERE 20, 220,387, 13
              AND 20, 222,387, 13
                AND 19, 258,258, 13
                  AND 18, 239,239, 13
                    = 17, 222,224, 19
                      TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 17, 222,222, 11
                        yyyymmdd 17, 222,222, 11
                      '20170221' 17, 224,224, 20
                    = 18, 241,243, 25
                      TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 18, 241,241, 17
                        scene_id 18, 241,241, 17
                      'band_list' 18, 243,243, 26
                  = 19, 260,262, 26
                    TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 19, 260,260, 17
                      action_id 19, 260,260, 17
                    'scene_enter' 19, 262,262, 27
                TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR 20, 279,387, 27
                  TOK_SUBQUERY_OP 20, 281,281, 27
                    IN 20, 281,281, 27
                  TOK_QUERY 22, 291,387, 12
                    TOK_FROM 22, 305,309, 12
                      TOK_TABREF 22, 307,309, 12
                        TOK_TABNAME 22, 307,307, 12
                          jpl_band_orc 22, 307,307, 12
                        x 22, 309,309, 25
                    TOK_INSERT 0, -1,385, 0
                      TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
                        TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
                          TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
                      TOK_SELECTDI 21, 292,296, 24
                        TOK_SELEXPR 21, 296,296, 24
                          TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 21, 296,296, 24
                            device_id 21, 296,296, 24
                      TOK_WHERE 26, 318,385, 15
                        AND 26, 320,385, 15
                          AND 25, 360,360, 15
                            AND 24, 339,339, 15
                              = 23, 320,322, 21
                                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 23, 320,320, 13
                                  yyyymmdd 23, 320,320, 13
                                '20170221' 23, 322,322, 22
                              = 24, 341,343, 27
                                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 24, 341,341, 19
                                  scene_id 24, 341,341, 19
                                'app_intro' 24, 343,343, 28
                            = 25, 362,364, 28
                              TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 25, 362,362, 19
                                action_id 25, 362,362, 19
                              'scene_enter' 25, 364,364, 29
                          = 26, 383,385, 29
                            TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 26, 383,383, 19
                              classifier 26, 383,383, 19
                            'app_intro' 26, 385,385, 30
                  TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 20, 279,279, 17
                    device_id 20, 279,279, 17
        s 26, 391,391, 46
      = 27, 404,412, 24
        . 27, 404,406, 13
          TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 27, 404,404, 12
            i 27, 404,404, 12
          device_id 27, 406,406, 14
        . 27, 410,412, 27
          TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 27, 410,410, 26
            s 27, 410,410, 26
          device_id 27, 412,412, 28
  TOK_INSERT 0, -1,425, 0
    TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
      TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
        TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
    TOK_SELECT 1, 0,23, 7
      TOK_SELEXPR 1, 2,4, 7
        TOK_ALLCOLREF 1, 2,4, 7
          TOK_TABNAME 1, 2,2, 7
            i 1, 2,2, 7
      TOK_SELEXPR 2, 11,23, 3
        TOK_FUNCTION 2, 11,21, 3
          from_unixtime 2, 11,11, 3
          TOK_FUNCTION 2, 13,18, 17
            unix_timestamp 2, 13,13, 17
            '20170221' 2, 15,15, 32
            'yyyyMMdd' 2, 17,17, 43
          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" 2, 20,20, 55
        bounce_date 2, 23,23, 81
    TOK_WHERE 0, 417,425, 0
      TOK_FUNCTION 0, 419,425, 0
        TOK_ISNULL 0, 425,425, 0
        . 28, 419,421, 10
          TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 28, 419,419, 9
            s 28, 419,419, 9
          device_id 28, 421,421, 11

scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for ASTNode type: 864, text: TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR :

" +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery in `WHERE` clause is not supported in Spark 1.6. It is supported in 2.0

Reference:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4226

Comment: Ah, Thanks. It looks like should be replaced by left joins.. : )